# Check aspect ratio of img via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I've been asking a css viable solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105556/how-to-center-images-in-a-responsive-grid-with-css-only-and-supporting-retina-di) for a responsive photo gallery with images of different ratios.
Unfortunately i guess it's too complicated to do this via css, so the only fast-easy solution is to use javascript to check the thumbnails aspect ratio and change the css inline for certain thumbs:
the script should check the `height:width` ratio of every thumbnail, if the ratio is lower than 0.6666666666666667 (2:3) then set via css `height:100%; max-width:none;` to override the actual rules. Can also be added a class, if easier.

How can this be done via javascript? (jquery can be used too as the library is already present for other plugins).

The structure of the grid is like this:

```
<ul id="gallery" class="gallery-grid">
  <li class="grid-block">
    <div class="block-wrap">
        <div class="link-wrap">
            <a href="<?php echo $photo->sourceImageFilePath; ?>" class="block-link" target="_blank" >
                <img class="block-thumb" src="<?php echo $photo->thumbImageFilePath; ?>"/>              
            </a>
        </div>  
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Ofcourse if you can find a viable css answer to my previous question is even more welcome! thanks!

Comment: If you search for "javascript get image height" in google you'll find a lot of results, don't be so lazy

Comment: Search a bit harder. I found a related topic just sitting on the first page of a Google search.

Comment: i guess i should have _specified_ somewhere that i'm fairly ignorant to what comes to javascript programming. Ofcourse i've been googlin around for this question, but i havent find something fairly easy to understand and implement to my own need, my bad, i guess...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might just want to query every *thumbnail* and do the math.

```
$('img').each(function(_, img) {
    var $this = $(this);

    if( $this.height() / $this.width() < 0.6666666666666667 ) {
        $this.css({
            height: '100%',
            maxWidth: 'none'
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hei i've implemented your code but unfortunately seems to work "inconsistently". Some times it applies the rule also to `img` elements that do respect the ratio, dunno why. My best guess is that the script can't read the original `src` while loading the page?

Comment: @Gruber: yes most definitely. You should either apply that code on each images `.load` callback, or go for the `window.onload` event which fires when **all** images were transfered and loaded (of course that might kick in quite late, you need to try).

Comment: Thank you. Something like this correct?
`$(window).load(function(){*your answer*}`
With this correction seem to work properly now, i'm asking because i'm really a novice with js.

Comment: @Gruber: yes, that should do it.

Comment: A little late to the topic with 7 years , but : What if my original image is 4608x3456 ,and the one in the DOM is 211x400 ,in order to fit in my image gallery. What should be my condition ?

Answer (score 12):

```
var ratio = $img.height() / $img.width();
if ( ratio < (2/3) ) { $img.css({ height: '100%', maxWidth: 'none' }) }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, your solutions works too, but @jAndy answered first so i gave the accept to him, upvoted anyway. thank you.